# creating background processes in my own shell

Tags: c, shell, unix

I am writing my own unix shell as a part of my assignment and I couldn't handle creating background processes. I wrote a signal-handling function and implemented the necessary(from my point of view-but obviously not good enough) parts to my code as follows :

```
void handler(int sig)
{
    int pid;
    int status;
    pid = wait(NULL);
    printf("[%d]retval: %d \n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main() { 
.....
....
struct sigaction sigchild; 
memset (&sigchild, 0, sizeof(sigchild)); 
sigchild.sa_handler = handler;
sigchild.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_NOCLDWAIT;
...
...
if(isBackground)  //background process
{
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sigchild, 0);
}
```

When I enter "sleep 5 &" for example and then enter "ps" to see the processes there is no sleep. What may be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not related to your question but you absolutely cannot use `printf()` in a signal handler.  You'll probably find that `wait()` in a signal handler is a disaster too.

Comment: Perhaps "man 3 daemon" could help? Afaik it's the easiest way to daemonize just about anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child is the background process. The parent is the foreground process. [SIGCHLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCHLD) is a signal sent to a parent when the child terminates. Change the `if (isbackground` to `if(!background)`

Comment: actually i am checking it like if(isBackground && !child).

Comment: You want the `sigaction` for the parent that is creating the child (background) processes. This will prevent zombie processes.